# How do I run an package after using apt-get to install it?

Tags: linux, command-line, package-management, utilities

I am currently using Linux (super new to this) and used apt-get to install a (package? app?) and am wondering how I am supposed to run it. I can't seem to find anything online as to how I can run these apps after installing them and am completely lost. I am doing this on an ARM64 machine.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the package you're trying to install and run. Yes, what you installed using apt-get is called a package.

1. Run it from the terminal. For example `$ chromium-browser` is all that is needed to run the chromium-browser once you have installed it. Or `$ gedit` would open the text editor.
2. You could pass an argument to the program. What the argument is interpreted as would depend on how the program is made. Sometimes it's a variable. Sometimes it's the name of the file. For example `$ gedit file.txt` would create a new file (or open the existing file.txt if it exists in the pwd) by the name of "file.txt" in the graphical text editor. If you're trying to compile a c program with gcc, then `$ gcc file.c`.
   In these cases, file.txt or file.c is called the *argument* you pass to the program you are trying to run.
3. Sometimes you have to tell the program to do something more extra and specific, or invoke an option provided within the program. For example, let us once again, take the example of gcc. `$ gcc file.txt -o file`.
   What *this* does is specify the name of the executable that is generated with `-o`. -o` in this case is called a "flag".

Programs installed by dpkg (apt-get) are usually installed in the /usr/bin folder or /usr/sbin folder and are accessible globally.
If you want to know what more your package is capable of doing, just type `$ man [PACKAGE-NAME]`, for example `$ man gcc` and read the manual page that appears.
Hope that helps.

Comment: That was super helpful, thank you!

Comment: I'm happy I could help, you're welcome!

Comment: There's no general rule that `man [PACKAGE-NAME]` will do anything (besides giving an error message). There's a unfortunate trend towards *not* writing man-pages for new programs, but even if there is a man page, it's probably named after the program not the package, a package might even include several programs each having their own man page.

Answer (score 0):

After the installation the app/binary with dependency is placed on your system. If the app has CLI interface then you have to type in the terminal.
Say if you've installed g++ with the `sudo apt-get install g++` then if you want to use this **g++** then simply type `g++` in your terminal and the app will run. If you want to read how to use this binary/app then you can type `man g++` or `man (your_binary_name)` and it will show how to use it.

Comment: Also, packages for GUI programs tend to add an icon and/or menu entry to the desktop environment (DE).  Sometimes multiple icons or menu entries, if the package contains multiple programs or has multiple ways of using the program.   Depending on the DE and the distribution, it might be added in alphabetical order or under some kind of section heading (e.g. "Games", "Graphics", "Multimedia", "Office", etc), or both.  Sometimes a program will appear in multiple appropriate categories.

Comment: Yes, the app has a CLI interface - I needed to launch it from my command line but just couldn't figure out how the whole apt-get things work. Thanks.

Comment: You want to know how apt-get work or how to launch the app from CLI?

Answer (score 0):

Package is a package: it contents lot of components necessary and helpful to run a program including manual pages. Some times the name of the package is the same as the name of the program. But more you can meet the name of a package (e.g. `net-tools`), which contents a group of programs, concerning the same goal. Here you are some helpful hints for CLI (command line interface):

`apt-file` is a very useful tool; with google you can find, that it is possible to set up your network interface with a command: `ifconfig`; you can try to write down it, but you did not installed its package; if you try to install it with:

```
apt-get install ifconfig
```

you get an error: *package not found*, because there is no package of the name ifconfig. The package `net-tools` contents also the `ifconfig` command, what you did not know before, hence you can use the apt-file, first you install it:

```
apt-get install apt-file
```

and you can ask it, which package contents the ifconfig command:

```
apt-file update
apt-file search ifconfig
```

Among the other answers you can find that the package name is `net-tools`.
You can filter the answers with `egrep` :

```
apt-file search ifconfig | egrep '\/ifconfig$'
```

to get less rows.

The `apt-file` can also tell you what other commands are packaged in:

```
apt-file list net-tools
```

As the programs are saved in some folder with name `bin` or `sbin` you can filter again:

```
`apt-file list net-tools | egrep '\/s`?bin\/'
```

And you can see that beside `ifconfig` there is included the command `netstat`, too.

Another useful command is a `dpkg`. This is a group of commands and basically you can use it to install a package downloaded (not from a repository)

```
dpkg -i some_package.deb
```

You can check whether you have some package installed yet:

```
dpkg -l name_of_package
```

Some packages ask during installation for your configuration decision. In fact, this is the job of `dpkg-reconfigure` which you can run when you need to change your basic configuration of the package:

```
dpkg-reconfigure some_package_name
```

While using Xwindows GUI (graphics user interface), you can use some of package manager e.g. `Synaptic`. Very close the such GUI manager you can use the CLI program `aptitude`.

```
apt-get install aptitude
```

In this program you can easily learn another Debian Linux feature: dependency. Lot of Linux programs are written not from scratch, but they use fine tuned programs from other Linux projects. Hence you must know, which package are necessary to be installed before you can use your program. This is called dependency and Debian packaging system keeps track of that in very sophisticated way. If you install two programs which needs the same library, you need not to install it twice, and if you remove (uninstall) one of those programs, the packaging system keeps the common library out of uninstallation.

I can recommend you to read some [intro](https://vitux.com/how-to-use-apt-to-install-programs-from-command-line-in-debian/) about Debian package installation, man pages of apt-get, apt-file, dpkg-..., aptitude etc.